# ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/STACK:10000000'

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I am trying to compile an OpenMP code, on Windows. The linker options [/stack:10000000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017) and [/largeaddressaware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/largeaddressaware-handle-large-addresses?view=msvc-170) are meant to be added, to avoid stack overflow errors. They are not recognised.
I think /largeaddressaware might be unnecessary as I am using a 64 bit compiler. But I do need to make /stack work.

I am using the "Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio 2022" and Intel Fortran to compile. It's not clear to me how the /stack flag is meant to be added, but here is what I tried:

```
ifort -c modules.f90 
ifort -c MainCode.f90 /openmp /STACK:10000000 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
ifort modules.obj MainCode.obj -o Code.exe /openmp /STACK:10000000 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
```

What I get is,

```
C:\Users\e\Desktop\code>ifort -c modules.f90
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler Classic for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.6.0 Build 20220226_000000
Copyright (C) 1985-2022 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\e\Desktop\code>ifort -c MainCode.f90 /openmp /STACK:10000000 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler Classic for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.6.0 Build 20220226_000000
Copyright (C) 1985-2022 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/STACK:10000000'
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE'

C:\Users\e\Desktop\code>ifort modules.obj MainCode.obj -o Code.exe /openmp /STACK:10000000 /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
Intel(R) Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler Classic for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 2021.6.0 Build 20220226_000000
Copyright (C) 1985-2022 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/STACK:10000000'
ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE'

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.33.31629.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-out:Code.exe
-subsystem:console
-defaultlib:libiomp5md.lib
-nodefaultlib:vcomp.lib
-nodefaultlib:vcompd.lib
modules.obj
MainCode.obj
```

Is there another command I could be using instead? Or am I using /stack wrong?

I tried both capital /STACK and lower case /stack. Neither worked. I also tried -large-address-aware as I had found that somewhere, but that didn't work either. I tried `/stack 10000000` too with no luck.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you may use the `/heap-arrays` option instead, which will drastically reduce the usage of the stack.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea as the code I'm running performs heavy calculations using large basis dimensions? Wouldn't reducing the usage of the stack also reduce the accuracy of the results?

Comment: Absolutely not, stack usage has nothing to do with accuracy. If your code cannot run because of stack overflow it's because there too many/too big arrays allocated on the stack. So either you increase the stack size, or you tell the compiler to allocate the arrays of the heap rather than on the stack. In theory this can be slower, but in practice there are many cases where the slowdown is unnoticeable.

Comment: It did seem a bit slower, but also it still gave stack overflow error even with `/heap-arrays`..

Comment: In the first place, you should investigate why your code needs so much space on the stack. Usually `heap-arrays` always solves the problem.

Comment: @Echo did you just specify `/heap-arrays` ? Note  also that `allocatable`(s) are by default stored in heap memory. Finally, as you also wrote, linker options do refer to the linker not the compiler. When invoking the compiler but you want to specify some link-time options, don't forget to put them after the `/link` compiler flag. Cheers :)

Comment: oh wow, adding `/link` WAS the solution. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must put `/link` (lowercase) on the line before linker options such as `/stack` and `/largeaddressaware`. This tells the compiler driver to pass them on to the linker.

There is a downside to setting a very large stack reserve value in that this reduces the 2GB Windows allocates for static code and data, plus some that Windows itself uses. This limit also applies to 64-bit Windows! Rather than start with an insanely large value, start at something like 1000000 and go up from there.

Comment: While you're here... Why doesn't `/heap-arrays` solve the problem here? That said I have had bad experiences with `/heap-arrays` in conjonction with OpenMP in the past (it was with ifort 14 on Linux, I don't know as of today).

Comment: I don't know - without a test program it's hard to guess. I'd also want to know what the OpenMP stack size was set to, and be able to see exactly where in the program the stack overflow occurred.